# How can I extract just the scheme, host, and port from a URL in Perl?

Tags: perl, url

I need to be able to extract just the scheme, host, and port from a URL.

So if my url in the browser is: `http://www.example.com:80/something.pl`
I need to be able to get the: `http://www.example.com:80`

Answer (score 9):

The [URI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/URI) module can help you slice and dice a URI any which way you want.

If you are trying to do this from within a CGI script, you need to look at `$ENV{SERVER_NAME}` and `$ENV{SERVER_PORT}`.

Using the `url` method of the CGI module you are using (e.g. [CGI.pm](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/CGI#OBTAINING_THE_SCRIPT%27S_URL) or [CGI::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/CGI::Simple#url%28%29_Return_the_script%27s_URL_in_several_formats)) will make things more straightforward.

Answer (score 6):

I let the URI module figure it out so I don't have to create new bugs:

```
use 5.010;
use URI;

my $url = 'http://www.example.com:80/something.pl';

my $uri = URI->new( $url );

say $uri->scheme;
say $uri->host;
say $uri->port;
```

Answer (score 3):

With [modperl](http://perl.apache.org/), it's in the [Apache2::RequestRec](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/api/Apache2/RequestRec.html#C_unparsed_uri_) object, using either `uri`,  or `unparsed_uri`.

You can't get the exact text typed into the user's browser from this, only what gets presented to the server.

The server name (virtual host) is in the Server object.

Answer (score -4):

```
sub cgi_hostname {
  my $h = $ENV{HTTP_HOST} || $ENV{SERVER_NAME} || 'localhost';
  my $dp =$ENV{HTTPS} ? 443 : 80;
  my $ds =$ENV{HTTPS} ? "s" : "";
  my $p = $ENV{SERVER_PORT} || $dp;
  $h .= ":$p" if ($h !~ /:\d+$/ && $p != $dp);
  return "http$ds\://$h";
}
```

Comment: @goe It seems you chose this answer because you do not want to use `CGI.pm` or `CGI::Simple`. I do not care which answer you pick, but not using a well established module for your CGI scripts is going to cost you in the long run.

Comment: Necromancing here...  What was all the hate about?  I think this is a great answer.  Of course, all due respect to using established modules if they fit the bill, etc. and that's great advice for the newbie programmers, etc. etc.  But if your needs are very simple, why burden yourself with a module that does a thousand time more?  If all one needs is what the OP asked, this code fits the bill, and quite well IMHO.